# determining leak in code - iphone

Tags: iphone, memory-leaks, instruments, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am using core data in my app, and have copied the same code generated by xcode for the fetched results controller(except that I am changing the cache name to nil). Nevertheless, the instruments tool shows a leak in my code for the fetchedResultsController, specifically for the variable aFetchedResultsController in the code below. Any idea why this is happening? Appreciate your inputs.thanks.

This is myModel class

```
- (NSFetchedResultsController *)fetchedResultsController {

    if (fetchedResultsController_ != nil) {
        return fetchedResultsController_;
    }

    /*
     Set up the fetched results controller.
     */
    // Create the fetch request for the entity.
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    // Edit the entity name as appropriate.
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:self.entityName inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];

    // Set the batch size to a suitable number.
    [fetchRequest setFetchBatchSize:20];

    // Edit the sort key as appropriate.
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:self.sortFieldName ascending:YES];
    NSMutableArray *sortDescriptors = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:sortDescriptor, nil];

    if(self.additionalSortField !=nil){
        NSSortDescriptor *additionalSortDescr = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:self.additionalSortField ascending:YES];
        [sortDescriptors addObject:additionalSortDescr];
        [additionalSortDescr release];
    }




    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    if(predicate != nil)
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];

    // Edit the section name key path and cache name if appropriate.
    // nil for section name key path means "no sections".
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext sectionNameKeyPath:sectionKeyName cacheName:nil];
    aFetchedResultsController.delegate = self;
    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;

    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    aFetchedResultsController = nil;
    [fetchRequest release];
    fetchRequest = nil;
    [sortDescriptor release];
    [sortDescriptors release];

    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![fetchedResultsController_ performFetch:&error]) {

        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);

    }

    return fetchedResultsController_;
}
```

This is where I am calling it

```
NSFetchedResultsController* fetchResults = myModel.fetchedResultsController;
```

Comment: are you using device or simulator? you should always check for leaks on a real device.

Comment: oh ok, thanks for that tip, I was using simulator, I will check on the device now.

Comment: Do you release the controller in dealloc?

Comment: Hi, Its the same on the device, yes, I am releasing it in dealloc. When I debug, I see that the variable aFetchedResultsController has an address allocated to it even before it is created for the first time. Then, when it comes to the statement with alloc, it changes to a new address. I suppose that this is the issue. But how come this local variable has an address allocated to this even before I have initialized it?

Answer (score -1):

NSFetchedResultsController* fetchResults declare in .h file